# Developing SSMS 17 extension using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssms, visual-studio-extensions

I am developing a extension using ToolWindow for ssms17 using vs2017,

[image: ToolWindow]

1. Created a menu under **View** => **Other Windows** => **ToolWindow1**
2. Followed https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1243356/Create-Your-Own-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-SSMS
3. Done changes in .vsct file for menu id and in Regedit as well.
4. The menu created has been loaded as follows,

[image: Tool Window Extension in SSMS view menu]

**Problem:**

Now, when I click ToolWindow1 i am not getting onclick event is being raised.

1. How should I subscribe to on click event
2. Or, how to display a menu when i do a right click in SSMS editor
3. Please suggest me good online resource for developing SSMS extension 17 using vs 17.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I found a [comment by Vitalii Tokarchyn](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1243356/Create-Your-Own-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-SSMS?msg=5538290#xx5538290xx) in the post you linked to that helped me fix this issue:

> It's because you use assemblies version 15, It's not compatible with
>   ssms. I replaced all my reference with references provided in this
>   tutorial (except Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools and
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK.EmbedInteropTypes). Also you can check log
>   file, I had there warnings about it

I removed all the existing references except the two Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools and Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK.EmbedInteropTypes and then re-installed using package manager console for version 14.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading -Version 14.0.50702
```

and

```
Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0 -Version 14.3.25407
```

Comment: I did face the same issue and fixed with the step you mentioned(I used VS 2017 for SSMS 17 extension)